# mark() and reset() method in Java

Tags: java, file, stream, reset, pushbackinputstream

According to the documentation,

**void mark(int readlimit):** Marks the current position in this input stream.
The mark method of PushbackInputStream **does nothing**.

**void reset():** Repositions this stream to the position at the time the mark method was last called on this input stream.
The method reset for class PushbackInputStream **does nothing** except throw an IOException.

> You can check above '**DOES NOTHING**'. So, If this is the case, Why
>   and Where this is useful ? In which situation I can use above both the
>   methods ?

and below is the example :

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.PrintWriter; 
import java.io.PushbackInputStream; 
public class PushbackInputStreamDemo  
{ 
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception 
    { 
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out, true); 
        String str = "GeeksforGeeks a computer science portal "; 
        byte b[] = str.getBytes(); 
        ByteArrayInputStream bout = new ByteArrayInputStream(b); 
        PushbackInputStream push = new PushbackInputStream(bout); 

        int c; 
        while((c=push.read())!=-1) 
        { 
            pw.print((char)c); 
        } 
        pw.println(); 

        // marking the position  
        push.mark(5); 

        // reseting is not supported throw exception 
        push.reset(); 

        pw.close(); 
    } 
}
```

> Above is the sample, But not getting what exactly both the methods
>   does. Please guide.

Comment: `PushbackInputStream.markSupported()` returns `false`. So you shouldn't be calling `mark`/`reset` anyway. And the javadocs of `mark` in that class clearly state that it does nothing.

Comment: ya that's the thing am confused for. If it does nothing then what's the matter of using it. By the way got the point now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mark` and `reset` methods are optional operations that not every InputStream needs to support. You can call `markSupported` to find out if it does.

PushbackInputStream does not support these methods.

The methods are still there, because they are defined in the `InputStream` interface. Maybe a bad design decision (could have been added to a separate interface), but that is how it is.

Comment: Maybe a bad design decision : For Sure.